# VBA Can I set name using integer?

Tags: vba, filter, integer

I want to do a looping where it will filter by few categories. My idea was to set using numbers so it would be easier to loop. My idea

```
For i = 1 to 5
myTable.AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=i
....
....
Next i
```

But I have to declare my categories first, so I thought of doing something like

```
1 = "MEN"
2 = "WOMEN"
3 = "KIDS BOY"
4 = "KIDS GIRL"
5 = "UNISEX"
```

But it seems that I cannot do so. So does anyone have any other idea on how to loop filters or know how to declare with integers. Thanks

Comment: Look into using a Scripting Dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something of the likes:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Filters()

    Dim MyFilter As Variant: MyFilter = setArrayFilters
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(MyFilter) To UBound(MyFilter)
        myTable.AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=MyFilter(i)
    Next i
    
End Sub
Private Function setArrayFilters() As Variant
    
    Dim x As Long: x = 5 'change this to redimension your array
    Dim arr(1 To x)
    arr(1) = "MEN"
    arr(2) = "WOMEN"
    arr(3) = "KIDS BOY"
    arr(4) = "KIDS GIRL"
    arr(5) = "UNISEX"
    setArrayFilters = arr
    
End Function
```